# Hund’s Rule - Please help explain below using Hunds rule?

Tags: physical-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry

Why is it easier to excite a 2s electron in a carbon atom to a 2p orbital than it would be to do the same in nitrogen?

Comment: No own attempt to answer it?

Comment: Yeah I do have my own attempt, obviously Hunds rule states that max multiplicity = max unpaired electrons = lowest energy. In carbons case you have 1s2 2s2 2p2, with the electrons in the p orbitals occupying 2px and 2py respectively, with up spin, maximising multiplicity. This is not the case for nitrogen (2p3, paired electrons,higher energy). Meaning that the energy required to excite an electron in the carbon atom from 2s to 2p would be less than it would be for nitrogen, in regards to hunds rule

Comment: I just wanted to get a rough idea of other peoples takes on it, note the question I’m asked is centred around hunds rule

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The question is too simple, because nitrogen's 2s electrons have higher Zeff. Comparing carbon and nitrogen: when you increase 1 proton and 1 electon, the electron has some shiending effect, so while the effective positive charge increases 1, the effective negative charge can't reach 1. In conclusion, it's easier to promote 2s>2p in carbon than in nitrogen atoms.

Also, this video might help you:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dXOyNaxhc4A&list=PLavaRHHaRimXdmzRB21Ew9abP66YvxKzh

Comment: There's a missing step in your logic: ionisation energy corresponds to the removal of the outermost electron (which is 2p in both cases), but here OP is asking for 2s -> 2p promotion.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't read it well.

Comment: The question I’ve been asked at university is asking to explain it using Hund’s Rule